# Is there a way to stop Selenium from going to other pages?

Tags: selenium, screen-scraping

I have a selenium-based scraper. Occasionally one of its locators fails in a way that is seemingly undetectable to me, and it "finds" the wrong button. Usually this isn't a big deal, since I expected it won't succeed 100% of the time, but the problem is, that button is leading me to a different session, thereby ending that entire session of scraping.

I was wondering if there is a way to configure selenium to temporarily not load any new pages and stay on the current page only, such that misclicks like this won't have any effect.

(Of course the ideal and "real" solution is to find a way to fix or detect the locator's mistake, but I want to have this at least as a temporary solution, if it is possible),

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to address _detect the locator's mistake_?

Comment: You could assert if the current url is on the right page otherwise.